# How to determine which topic each Test Tweet is addressing to?

Tags: nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling, tweets

I implemented LDA using python and modeled topics for a set of tweets and trying to map each tweet to topic to see which topic does the tweet belong to but I couldn't find any help online.

Although I found that this could be done for NMF but I couldn't find any functions or any specific options in python for this specific case, I'm using gensim for generation of topic using LDA

Answer (score 1):

Using your trained model to get the most-associated topics for any particular text is covered in the Gensim docs for the `LdaModel` class, under 'Usage Examples' - https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#usage-examples – but the treatment there may be a little unituitive, because:

- it calls any text you might be analyzing an 'unseen' document, but the same process works for documents that were part of the training corpus; and
- like many other Gensim classes, the analysis is done via Python's indexed-lookup idiom. That is, bracketed `[` `]`-accessing (aka the shortcut for calling `.__getitem__()`), using the right representation of the text **as if** it were a lookup key, even though in truth here it's an argument to the model's analysis rather than something strictly looking-up some stored response.

So this part of its examples is what you need to follow:

> Query, the model using new, unseen documents
>
> ```
> >>> # Create a new corpus, made of previously unseen documents.
> >>> other_texts = [
> ...     ['computer', 'time', 'graph'],
> ...     ['survey', 'response', 'eps'],
> ...     ['human', 'system', 'computer'] 
> ... ]
> >>> other_corpus = [common_dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in other_texts]
> >>>
> >>> unseen_doc = other_corpus[0]
> >>> vector = lda[unseen_doc]  # get topic probability distribution for a document
> ```

Just remember:

- the `other_texts` & `unseen_document` in this example can also be repeats from the training corpus, to ask the trained model what it thinks those doc's toppics should be; and
- you need to convert any text to a bag-of-words representation using the *exact same* dictionary as was used for training documents, so that word-indexes and frequency-weightings are proper for the bag-of-words representations used for lookups.